# Python tkinter grid, row value being ignored in a ScrolledText Widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to have a space between the Entry widget and the ScrollText Widget. I thought it would be as simple as setting row=2 for the grid. The strange thing is no matter what I set for row the ScrollText widget always starts at row 1. I suppose I could add an empty text widget to make the space but I am confused as to why setting the row is not working for me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

main = Tk()
main.title("Grid Prob")
main.geometry('750x750')


text = StringVar()
entSearch = Entry(main, textvariable = text, width = 50, font='arial 12',
                  highlightthickness=1)
entSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

txt = """This is some text to be entered into the text widget. It should 
word wrap when the text exceeds the width of the widget."""
textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main,width=70,height=33)

# No matter what number I put for row the scroll widget always starts in 
# row 1
textw.grid(column=1, row=3)

textw.config(background="light grey", foreground="black",
             font='arial 12', wrap='word')
textw.insert(END, txt)    

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: empty rows have a height of zero.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: After creating a few more test cases I think I understand what you are saying now. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted what Bryan Oakley said in the comments above correctly the problem is that since my code didn't put anything into row 2 by default it (row 2) has a height of 0. This means that I am putting my ScrollText Widget into row 3 as intended but since row 2 has a height of 0 visually it looks like it's being placed in row 2. I added a blank label to my code with a height of one and placed it on row 2. This provided the space that I was looking for. Here is the additional code I added.

```
label_1 = Label(main, width = "70", height = "1")
label_1.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
```

It seems weird that tkinter makes you add widgets just to provide a space. If anyone knows of a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: You can use the `grid_rowconfigure` method to set the minimum size of an empty row.